# A FileWriter actor in Akka/Scala

Tags: scala, akka

I am writing an Akka/Scala app, in which many actors interact. Some of these interactions give rise to results that I would like to save to a file. My current idea is to have a single FileWriter actor that receives the results from all other actors, and appends them to a file kept open during the entire run.

1. is this a reasonable approach?
2. what should i watch out for when implementing the FileWriter?

Comment: are you required to write all the data to a single file or can there be multiple files?

Comment: @4aRkKn1gh7 : not required, but it would be most convenient. There shouldn't be huge amounts to write, I just want the solution to be non-blocking for the rest of the app.

Comment: well if the data is not too much then you can use a single actor which would collect data from all the actors. But you would have to have some sort of a queuing mechanism at that actor to store the data to be written

Comment: @4aRkKn1gh7 *some sort of a queuing mechanism at that actor to store the data to be written* huh? what for? isn't usual actor queue not enough?

Comment: @om-nom-nom what if the actor queue becomes full when the actor is busy saving data if would then cause messages(data) to be dropped.

Comment: I think it's perfectly reasanable approach, [in fact something like this was done in respect to network io](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io-tcp.html)

Comment: @4aRkKn1gh7 no, if you use BoundedMailbox, this way producer actor will be blocked on send once queue reaches it's limit. [There are other options as well](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/mailboxes.html)

Comment: I'd look into AsynchronousFileChannel for writing. This would be non-blocking and you could allocate region of a file with map method.